# CKEditor, Plugin Conflict

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, conflict

I recently started to use CKEditor, i have come across to somewhat a weird problem, i have downloaded two plugins ,the "texttransform" and "autogrow",my config file looks like this ,,,

```
****CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'texttransform'
config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';
};****
```

The problem is, at one time only one plugin is active and functionality of other plugin disappears, for example,when i added autogrow, the control buttons of texttransform disappears,and they only work when i remove the line "config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow';" from my config file, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the configuration incorrectly. You must set `config.extraPlugins` only once, with two plugin names:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
   config.extraPlugins = 'autogrow,texttransform';
};
```

See also the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins).